# Where to put Thorntail Swarm Configuration (project-defaults.yml) within a multi module Gradle project?

Tags: wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I'm trying to configure the Swarm AS based on Thorntail `2.5.0.Final` with a `project-defaults.yml` within a multi-module Gradle project. Unfortunately the configuration file doesn't get picked up.

Where do I have to put the `project-defaults.yml` file so it's registered by Thorntail?

Currently the situation looks like this:
[image: Current sitatuion]

I think the sub module resources folder is not correct, because this configuration file should configure the whole AS, right?

Answer (score 1):

The file belongs to `src/main/resources`. It seems you already have one there -- are the two different?

If you have a multi-module project, generally there should be one module that builds the uberjar, and that module should have `src/main/resources/project-defaults.yml`.

Comment: I have one in my sub project resources, but it doesn't get picked up. Does it make sense to have a `project-defaults.yml` within a sub module?

Comment: How to configure the uberjar?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on the Gradle plugin we have. I can recommend these examples: https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples/tree/2.5.0.Final/gradle-examples/multi-module